# Slim Framework 4 com Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, api, laravel-eloquent, slim, slimframework

Estou utlizando o Slim-Framework na versão 4 para criação de api e gostaria de utilizar junto o Eloquent para facilitar a manipulação com o banco de dados.
Porém não encontrei nenhum material/exemplo de como utilizar ele no projeto.

O único material oficial que encontrei foi nesse [link](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/database-eloquent.html) mas a estrutura é da versao 3 do Slim e não está atualizada.

Fiz o clone desse [repositório](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) para ser trabalhado e há um arquivo chamado 'dependencies.php' acho que provavelmente a conexão seria encaixado aqui, como posso fazer isso? Ou é melhor eu utilizar a versão 3 do SlimFramework?

**dependencies.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        LoggerInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
            $settings = $c->get('settings');

            $loggerSettings = $settings['logger'];
            $logger = new Logger($loggerSettings['name']);

            $processor = new UidProcessor();
            $logger->pushProcessor($processor);

            $handler = new StreamHandler($loggerSettings['path'], $loggerSettings['level']);
            $logger->pushHandler($handler);

            return $logger;
        },
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisa fazer algumas passos como por exemplo adicionar as configurações de conexão no arquivo `settings.php` da pasta `app` da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Monolog\Logger;

return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    // Global Settings Object
    $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        'settings' => [
            'displayErrorDetails' => true, // Should be set to false in production
            'logger' => [
                'name' => 'slim-app',
                'path' => isset($_ENV['docker']) ? 'php://stdout' 
                                                 : __DIR__ . '/../logs/app.log',
                'level' => Logger::DEBUG,
            ],
            'db' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'database' => 'db',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'senha',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
};
```

após essa configuração dentro da pasta `src` crie uma pasta `Models` (`src\Models`) colocando ai seus `Models` e uma configuração de conexão que será utilizado no arquivo de rotas, exemplo:

Crie o arquivo para que possa subir as configurações do `Eloquent`:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

final class Bootstrap
{
    public static function load($container)
    {        
        $settings = $container->get('settings');            
        $capsule = new Capsule();        
        $capsule->addConnection($settings['db']);
        $capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));
        $capsule->setAsGlobal();
        $capsule->bootEloquent();                
    }
}
```

e como exemplo um `Model` com o nome de `User` (só para testar):

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Para finalizar entre dentro de `app\routes.php` e logo abaixo a linha: `$container = $app->getContainer();` escreve a linha `Bootstrap::load($container);` que é responsável em subir as configurações do `Eloquent`:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use App\Application\Actions\User\ListUsersAction;
use App\Application\Actions\User\ViewUserAction;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Interfaces\RouteCollectorProxyInterface as Group;

use App\Models\Bootstrap;
use App\Models\User;

return function (App $app) {
    $container = $app->getContainer();    
    Bootstrap::load($container);

    $app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->getbody()->write(json_encode(User::all()->toArray()));         
        return $response;
    });

    $app->group('/users', function (Group $group) use ($container) {
        $group->get('', ListUsersAction::class);
        $group->get('/{id}', ViewUserAction::class);
    });
};
```

o exemplo acima tem a linha do `Model Eloquent`:

```
$response->getbody()->write(json_encode(User::all()->toArray()));
```

que vai imprimir os dados da tabela de `users` onde o `Eloquent` foi configurado.

***Observações:***

*Pacotes que deverão ser instalados para que esse exemplo funcione*:

- `"doctrine/dbal"`
- `"illuminate/database"`
- `"illuminate/events"`
- `"illuminate/filesystem"`
- `"illuminate/pagination"`
- `"monolog/monolog"`